# gmail gets crashed with following code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

the use case of my chrome extension is to highlight the text and create those highlighted text a hyperlink in the gmail messages, if the text matches with the list of topics. For this I tried with just 6 topics though gmail gets crashed. In real, the list of topic will be 1000 +

What i have done is at the document load, I have called the fetchTopics function(in real api is called to fetch the topics) and inside that function i iterated over topicData object and pass the topic one by one to searchPage function and assigned to the `re` variable for checking if the provided topic match with the text inside gmail inbox message.

Here is my code

```
var topicData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Courses'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'miss'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'out'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'your'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'savings'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'and'
    }
];

function fetchTopics() {
    // const apiUrl = `http://localhost:3020/v2/emails`;
    // const headers = new Headers();
    // headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return topicData.map(datum => {
        return searchPage(datum.name);
    });
    // fetch(apiUrl, {
    //  method: 'GET',
    //  headers
    // })
    //  .then(function(response) {
    //      return response.json();
    //  })
    //  .then(function(data) {
    //      topicData.map(datum => searchPage(data.name));
    //  })
    //  .catch(function(err) {
    //      console.log('err', err);
    //  });
}

/*  the searchPage function takes an argument which is going
to set the variable re. Then iterate through topic array and call the searchPage function
for each value inside it while passing that value to the function
*/
function searchPage(topic) {
    console.log('topic', topic);
    var re = new RegExp(topic, 'g'); // example regex that the function will use for search
    var regs;

    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        document.body,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        function(node) {
            if ((regs = re.exec(node.textContent))) {
                if (!node.parentNode.classList.contains('highlighted_text')) {
                    var match = document.createElement('A');
                    match.appendChild(document.createTextNode(regs[0]));
                    match.href = `https://app.com/CustomTopic/${
                        regs[0]
                    }`;
                    match.classList.add('highlighted_text');

                    var after = node.splitText(regs.index);
                    after.nodeValue = after.nodeValue.substring(regs[0].length);
                    node.parentNode.insertBefore(match, after);
                }
            }
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
        },
        false
    );

    walker.nextNode();
}

// Run when the whole document loads
$(window).bind('load', function() {
    document.addEventListener('click', init);
    fetchTopics();
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide the error logs?

Comment: no i dont get the error but gmail gets hanged. I have to close from activity monitor then. There it shows 1.2gb memory sometimes even more than that. Am i doing this in inefficient way?